# Easy way to analyze traces in Micro Services architecture

Tags: c#, python, architecture, microservices, distributed-system

### Background

I have a system that distributing tasks with queues. I have N services that communicate with each other with N queues.

My system diagram looks like this: 
[image]

As you can see, the outcome results performance depends on multiple services. So, diagnose failures (or performance issues) is hard task - it's very hard to find which part of the chain was the problem.

I was looking for a tool that will provide me a map of all the processing traces. Something like this:

[image]

With a visual diagram like this, I can find which part of the chain was the problem. Easily.

### Question

So, I found a few solutions that aim to solve this problem:

- [Open Tracing](https://opentracing.io/)
- [Open Census](https://opencensus.io)

Unfortunately, it looks very difficult to:

- Install: those tools depend on multiple other tools (Zipkin, Jagger and many more).
- Configure: not an easy task. The documentation is pretty narrow for the creator site.

Am I wondering if I can have an easier solution for this simple problem?

Comment: Where are you deploying your services ? Have you considered Application insights if that fits your case?

Comment: I'm using Google Cloud. Application insight is not suitable for this environment.

Comment: Depending on your tech stack you may want to use traceability and monitoring libraries in your application? That way you can obtain custom granular control over performance metrics and diagnostics as well.

Comment: I'm using C# and Python. I want to monitor the whole processing chain. Therefore, I think that it is necessary to have a 3rd part to trace the whole process.

Comment: I create a wrapper over flask and opentracing @No1Lives4Ever. See this [tutorial](https://py-ms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_propagate_traces/) I hope this library could help you :)